# Xcode 9.1 (and 9.2) - Referenced sprites are not executing Actions added in Scene Editor

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have come across some unexpected behaviour when using the SpriteKit Scene Editor, and wonder if anyone else is having the same issue.

I created a sprite in a scene and added Actions to move it around using the Scene Editor. The Actions play fine when I click the animate button on the editor. I add a reference to this scene to the main scene using the SKReferenceNode object in the Scene Editor, and the sprite appears in the main scene as expected in the Editor. When I build and run the app however, the sprite appears but no Actions run. I have tried this on the Xcode 9.2 beta and get the same result.
If I load the sprite scene directly from the main view controller, all the Actions execute as expected, so it seems to be an issue with referenced nodes.
I also found that if I override didMove(to:) in the main scene swift class, and put a breakpoint in it, then just hit continue when it hit the breakpoint, all Actions play on referenced sprites as expected. If I disable the breakpoint, no Actions play on referenced sprites.
(So my workaround is to simply use the breakpoint, and hit the continue button)

Another interesting observation. I opened a sample project created with an older version of Xcode, and referenced sprites executed their Actions fine. I copied this older SKS file into my project and Actions worked fine...until I edited the SKS file (added another Action), then they never worked again.

Comment: There is a bug where isPaused is set to true in the beginning,  when your scene moves to the view, call scene.isPaused = false to reset all the nodes

Comment: That got it, thanks. Funnily enough, after experimenting with setting isPaused on numerous nodes of the SKReferenceNode as well as the referenced Scene to get it to work, once it was working I iteratively removed them all, and now it works without any modification...strange one.

Comment: you don't need to iterate, scene.isPaused does the iteration for you (Terrible design on their part)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: in Xcode 10, scene.isPaused is false, but any nodes brought in through a reference node, either in GameScene.sks or through resolve() are paused.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem and it was driving me crazy. I tried setting the .isPaused on the scene and on the individual sprites. Nothing worked except the insert breakpoint method. That is not a solution.

What I discovered was if I set the is paused to true and false (which is the value I wanted) then it worked for all the sprites.

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.isPaused = true
    self.isPaused = false
}
```

This is a pretty annoying bug in scene editor that should be fixed.

Comment: This worked for me. The issue is still there as of xcode 10.1 :/

Comment: The bug exists in 11.1

Comment: 12.5 and still there

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question just the other day:
[XCode 9: SKEditorReference doesn't allow animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647022/xcode-9-skeditorreference-doesnt-allow-animations)

The only way I was able to get this to work was to put the isPaused on the exact sprite node I was trying to animate (within a ref node - I had created an entire sks scene/file and drag-dropped that into my main scene).

I tried isPaused=false at the top level, main scene didMove to view to no effect, and then added isPaused=false to the main reference node, to no effect. It worked only when I added isPaused=false the actual sprite I was trying to animate. I removed isPaused=false from the the main & ref nodes, and as long as it was still on the sprite node (within the ref node) I was trying to animate: success.

Bottom line seems to be that isPaused=false is required on any sprites within a reference node.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，I had this same problem. Below is my solution:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    sleep(1)
}
```

However,this is not good way. I hope I can help you temporarily.
If you slove this problem or find a better solution, please reply me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this problem persists in Xcode10. If you are using custom classes, either directly or as the parent node, the easiest way to fix this is to add `self.isPaused = false` to the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method of your custom class.