# Xcode 9: SKEditorReference doesn't allow animations?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I can't seem to get sprite nodes that have been added by reference (drag/drop one sks file into another sks file in Xcode 9) to animate. This seems allowable, as you can physically do such a thing, but I'm unsure why the sub-nodes won't animate.

Example
1. Start with standard spritekit template
2. add a HUD.sks file, and add a color sprite somewhere, name it "hudSpriteNode"
3. drag the HUD.sks file into the GameScene.sks scene - center it at zero
4. find the hudSpriteNode (by name)
5. move it with .position (works!)
6. move it with animation (fails!)

HUD.sks
[image: HUD.sks screenshot]

GameScene.sks
[image: GameScene.sks screenshot]

Add this code to GameScene.swift

```
if let testSpriteNode = childNode(withName: "//hudSpriteNode") as? SKSpriteNode {
  print("Found test sprite node")
  print("Test node position 1: \(testSpriteNode.position)")
  testSpriteNode.position = CGPoint.zero
  print("Test node position 2: \(testSpriteNode.position)")
  testSpriteNode.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 200, y: 200, duration: 4))
}
```

Run... position is moved correctly, but animation fails.

Comment: try to set the isPaused property of your scene to false when it moves to the view. Have a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615847/xcode-9-1-and-9-2-referenced-sprites-are-not-executing-actions-added-in-scen

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. That mostly did the trick with some additional updates/validation on my part.

Answer (score 2):

See link by @Marcel in the comments. The post he pointed me to mostly did the trick with some additional updates/validation on my part. The only way I was able to get this to work, though, was to put the isPaused on the exact sprite node I was trying to animate (within my ref node).

I tried isPaused=false at the top level, main scene didMove to view, but to no effect, and then added isPaused=false to the main reference node, to no effect. It worked only when I added isPaused=false the actual sprite (within the ref node I had added) I was trying to animate. I removed isPaused=false from the the main & ref nodes, and as long as isPaused=false was still on the sprite node in question (the one within the ref node I was trying to animate): success.

Bottom line seems to be that isPaused=false is required on any sprites contained within reference nodes.