# xcode 10.1 scene-kit animation - Resources - Bug?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm reading through "2D Apple Games through tutorial" learning the Xcode IDE. Chapter 7 leads you through using scene kit to make animations using resources.

They sound great...

The problem is I can't get them to work. The app loads to sim or device fine but the animations don't start.

I've been to the publisher website and downloaded the resources, which contains a project file. The project file works. until you add another animation to the file and then the same thing happens.

[Link to project files](https://raywenderlich.com/store/2d-ios-tvos-games-by-tutorials/source-code)

Is this a bug on Xcode 10.1 ? and if it is, does any one know a work around? Should I raise this on an apple forum \o/?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue as detailed here. Issue is still present on Xcode 10.1

[Xcode 9.1 (and 9.2) - Referenced sprites are not executing Actions added in Scene Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615847/xcode-9-1-and-9-2-referenced-sprites-are-not-executing-actions-added-in-scen)

Inside Scene didMove() method call add

```
isPaused = true
isPaused = false
```